# SQL*Loader ORA-01821

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

So, apparently in Oracle 12.2 the following works

`SDATE TIMESTAMP "YYYYMMDDHH24MISS",`

But in 12.1, not so much.

`SQL*Loader-951: Error calling once/load initialization
ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

I have exactly the same ldr file on two different databases, one works and one not.
I don't really want to change the extract program to shorten the timestamp, but when I try an inline
`"to_timestamp(substr(:SDATE,1,12), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')"` I get the same error.

Can someone shed any light? My brain is spinning around this a bit too fast.

Basically: I have a solution to the immediate problem, run it on the other server.
However, someone is going to want to know why, and "'cause it doesn't work otherwise" doesn't cut it for non-tech folks. :) 
If anyone else has seen this and/or knows the document number, that would help.

Comment: what does sdate timestamp returns

Comment: That is a line from the sql loader command file.

Comment: In case someone asks: the exact same ldr file, and data, works when run on a 12.2 machine, loading the data into the 12.1 database.